# Function composition inverse problem

Tags: functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Is there any general way to find a function $f$ for which $f\circ f = f(f(x))= g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is given?

Comment: You want to google on the term "functional square root".

Comment: Not only there is no general way, but the answer is typically ugly, and moreover, rarely unique.

Comment: An early, nice article (it is in german, don't know whether there is an english version) is by Ernst Schroeder about 1870 where he developed his idea of iterating functions which have a fixpoint. After him was the "Schroeder"-method, the "Schroederfunction" named (This is also in wikipedia) Moreover you can find some material about it in mathoverflow. Perhaps a very basic, amateurish introduction of mine using "Carlemanmatrices" would interest you, see then http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ContinuousfunctionalIteration.pdf

Comment: There is no general formula for this; you have to do it function by function. If you give us an example of $f(x)$, one of us could find its functional root so you have some idea of what has to be done. Some functions, however, have no real closed-form functional root.